# PHP preg_replace for specific characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've got multiple strings in my array:

```
test/01-about-us/01-some-different-title
test/01-about-us/02-some-12345-title
test/01-about-us/03-12345-title
test/02-contact-us/01-foo
test/02-contact-us/02-bar
test/02-contact-us/02-foo-bar
```

What to do:
if a string contains numbers between each forward slash and first hyphen
remove the digits and the hyphen

Required output:

```
test/about-us/some-different-title
test/about-us/some-12345-title
test/about-us/12345-title
test/contact-us/foo
test/contact-us/bar
test/contact-us/foo-bar
```

What regex would be suitable for that?

Comment: Replace `#/\d+-#` with `/`. Next time it'll cost you to get free work done ;)

Comment: So fast and it really works, thanks a lot. I'll buy you a drink next time :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `#/\d+-#` with `/`. …
                    – Niet the Dark Absol